# _CrtCheckMemory usage example

Tags: windows, debugging, heap-memory, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to understand how to use `_CrtCheckMemory` to track down heap corruption in a Windows application I'm working on. I can't seem to get it to return `false`. Here's my test code:

```
int* test = new int[1];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    test[i] = 1;
}
assert( _CrtCheckMemory( ) );
```

In the code above, `_CrtCheckMemory( )` returns true. I'm running in Debug mode. What else do I need to do in order to get a simple example of `_CrtCheckMemory` flagging a problem?

Answer (score 7):

An extra step is required, you must convince the compiler to replace the default *new* operator with the debug allocator.  Only the debug allocator creates the "no-mans land" areas that detect an under- or overwrite of the heap block.  It is risky, code that's compiled with the original allocator will not mix well with code that wasn't.  So it forces you to opt-in explicitly.

That's best done in the pre-compiled header file (stdafx.h by default) so you can be sure that *all* code uses the debug allocator.  Like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#  define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#  define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
#  include <crtdbg.h>
#  include <assert.h>
#endif
```

The CRTDBG macros get the malloc() functions and the *new* operators replaced.

Do beware that your code as posted will trigger another diagnostic first.  On Windows Vista and up, the Windows heap allocator is going to complain first because the code destroyed the Windows heap integrity.  Make the overwrite a bit subtler by indexing only up to, say, 2.

Comment: Hmmm. Added your precompiler stuff to stdafx.h and a dependent project, and still not stopping after my array overwrite. I will scratch my head on this one a bit. Apparently there's something called gflags which may also be able to help me with this.

Comment: I tested this before I posted, using your code.  Worked fine.  Gflags is useful if you use other tooling, like umhd.exe

Comment: Thanks. Setting up a new, dead-simple project just so I can see this _CrtCheckMemory actually work.

Comment: I tested this on MSVS 2017 and it unfortunately doesn't work.