# CRT delete IGNORE_BLOCK causes ASSERT_FAULT

Tags: c++, crt

I use a library that is being devloped by an outsourcer. It has a memory leak. In order to debug my application I alwayas have to know that new change do not cause new memory leaks.

What I've done is that all blocks selected in their library have an IGNORED_BLOCK status.

But when i try this, Visual Studio fails with AssertFault:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <assert.h>


void main( )
{
  delete new(_IGNORE_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) int;
}
```

Comment: You'll see _IGNORE_BLOCK when you didn't turn on the debug allocator.  Those blocks are ignored in memory leak reports because no debug info is available for them.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13182286/17034

Comment: `pHead->nLine == IGNORE_LINE && pHead->lRequest == IGNORE_REQ`
http://tinypic.com/r/29kp6yr/6
witch mean that ignore not required?